# one form submision to 2 controllers in laravel

Tags: database, forms, laravel, controller, models

so i have 2 tables in my db: example students and hobbies.
so that means 2 controllers as well StudentController and HobbyController.
and as well 2 models.

i have a form where it takes for example:

- 1.student name
- 2.age
- 3.height
- 4.weight
- 5.bmi
- 6.hobby
- 7.schedule
- 8.intensity
- 9.diet

the first five has to go to studentcontroller 
and the 6-9 goes to hobbycontroller..
how shud i do this? i dont want 2 different forms ...

Comment: You can use redirect to [action](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/responses#redirecting-controller-actions) method  or you can extract that logic to a service

Comment: thx for the suggestion..going with extract to a service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might not be the best answer but you could use single form to pass to the a controller and then pass the data to the multiple repositories.

**route.php**

```
Route::resource('student', 'StudentController');
```

**StudentController.php**

```
public function __constructor(StudentRepository $student, HobbyRepository $hobby)
{
    $this->student = $student;
    $this->hobby= $hobby;
}

public function store(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->all();
    $hobby = [
        'hobby' => $data['hobby'],
        'schedule' => $data['schedule'],
        'intensity' => $data['intensity'],
        'diet' => $data['diet'],
    ];
    $student = [
        'student_name' => $data['student_name'],
        'age' => $data['age'],
        'height' => $data['height'],
        'weight' => $data['weight'],
        'bmi' => $data['bmi'],
    ];

    $this->student->store($student);
    $this->hobby->store($hobby);

    //your other codes.
}
```

**StudentRepository.php**

```
public function store($data)
{
   // your implementation on storing the user.
}
```

**HobbyRepository.php**

```
public function store($data)
{
   // your implementation on storing the hobby.
}
```

You could use any method and variables to pass the data from controller. Hope this helps.

Edit:

For your extended question on the storing and retrieving information.

As stated in the docs:

```
The create method returns the saved model instance:

$flight = App\Flight::create(['name' => 'Flight 10']);
```

For more information refer to the docs:

> https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#inserts

If you want to pass the `student id` to the `hobby` the simplest method is to return the student from `StudentRepository` and pass it to the `HobbyRepository`.

E.g:

**StudentRepository.php**

```
public function store($data)
{
   // your implementation on storing the user.
   $student = [] // array of the student informations to be stored.
   return Student::create($student); //you will have student information here.
}
```

**StudentController.php**

```
$student = $this->student->store($student); //store the student information and get the student instance.
$this->hobby->store($hobby, $student->id); //pass it to the hobby to store id.
```

You should change the `hobbyRepository` store to use the `student id`.

This might fix your extended problem.

Comment: thxxx for the effort ! this methodis exciting! which i have learnt from my previous question that you answered ... im gonna try it out..before that i have a prob in my form... for the enum data type .. i have a table columns that is enum type.. so when i submit the form it gives me data truncated error.. any idea ?

Comment: @paladin...fixed the enum data type..no worries bro :D

Comment: Okey great. ;) Hope you will find the best path soon :D

Comment: btw @PaladiN ....now if i want to set relationship ...between student and hobby. which is a one to one relationship. where will i assign the function? as in the laravel examples they assign it in the controllers of each model..in my case i shud assign it in the studentcontroller?

Comment: If you want two way relationship you should add the relationship function on your both `class Model` i.e. : `Student.php` `Hobby.php` and if you want the relationship from single way you could add on either side only. https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships
`You should define the relationship in Model and not in controller.`

Comment: ohh right...sorry @@ i misunderstood ...thxx a lot..i will go about doing it now

Comment: i have pretty much made it to this level where i can save data from one form to 2 different tables..now for the relationship defining ...i set them in the model..but the problem now is ..im saving both student and hobby data at one go...how can i get the student id then save the hobby?

Comment: @MohamedManas You could read the edited answer. It might be useful for your comment's question.

Comment: thxx @paladiN i got the studentid successfully... thxx now im trying to get the student->hobby...its only returning collecion..how do i get a particular value of  diet ...like hobby['diet']

Comment: hi paladiN.... right now im editing the update form for the above..as you know its one form ... i have a problem now...for the hobby model ..when i insert into the database i converted it into json encoded string..now retreiving the model i need to decode the string..which i did..but when i try to form bind..it says calling undefined object...

Comment: How are you storing the data in the database and retriving? In general we don't need to json encode the data to store in the database. Could you explain more with examples as i cannot say like this.

Comment: sorry for the late reply, its ok now ... the reason i had to json encode is because.. from my form i had to combine 3 field's input into one ..so i used json encode to combine them to json encoded string..then when trying to edit the form..i had to decode so i can populate the form's field back with the values.. it was a bit of hassle..but i had to do it that way