# How to get the ID of the latest record just inserted?

Tags: database, forms, laravel, relationship

I'm trying to insert data into 2 different tables with relationship .. for example `student` and `hobby`. so `student->hasOne(hobby)` and `hobby->belongsTo(student)`.

I'm inserting all this info at one go ..in one form for your reference in doing something like this: [one form submision to 2 controllers in laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42240354/one-form-submision-to-2-controllers-in-laravel/42240708?noredirect=1#comment71651277_42240708).

Now my question is how do I save the hobby with the same id as of student? 
If I was saving `student` first then another form to save `hobby` then I can easily get the `student_id` first then I can save the `hobby` with the user id.

Comment: Are you talking about MySQL tables or HTML tables, or some other kind of table?

Comment: sorry forgot to mention..its mysql table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about `insertGetId()`?

```
$studentId = DB::table('students')->insertGetId(
    ['name' => 'John']
);
```

Then you can use te ID for tasks that relate to other models:

```
DB::table('hobbies')->inset(
    ['student_id' => $studentId, 'hobby' => $hobby]
);
```

You can find more about queries here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries

Answer (score 1):

You can submit to one controller. Easier. Then do

```
$student = Student::create([
    'name' => $request->name,
    ...
]);

$hobby = Hobby::create([
    'student_id' => $student->id,
    'schedule' => $request->schedule,
    ...other data
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

thx for the answers guys ..i did it by getstudentid() method and passing the student id...after creating the student.

Answer (score -1):

You can insert it using the relation without even care about the id.

```
$hobby = auth()->user()->hobby()->create([
    'hobby_column1' => 'bla bla bla',
    'hobby_column2' => 'bla bla bla',
]);
```

In the example I use `auth()->user()`, but it can be any instance of `User` class.

Check [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#the-create-method) to better understand what you can do with relations.

Clearly you'll be able to get the id in `$hobby`, simply using `$hobby->id` once created.